# Removal of capitals and spaces in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm creating a module in Opencart and have used the standard 'model' to add an array into the database. Unfortunately when I retrieve via

```
$this->data['font'] = unserialize($this->config->get('selectfont'));
```

The information has removed the capital letters and spaces between the words. How can I add the capitals and spaces back into the variables? Sorry been racking my brains over this for days. Help much appreciated.

Davetoff

Ok so I've done some digging around in the back and basically the POST command puts the data into the database via serialize:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            foreach ($this->request->post as $key => $value) {
                $this->request->post[$key] = serialize($value);
            }
```

So when I retrieve it via:

```
$this->data['font'] = unserialize($this->config->get('selectfont'));
```

it should work but doesn't. I've attached a line of the sort of data field I have in the data base:

a:6:{i:0;s:11:"segoescript";i:1;s:5:"serif";i:2;s...etc etc

This should unserialize...right?

Help please.

Comment: Can you give the data before serialization instead of $this->config->get('selectfont')?

Comment: The input data was: Segeo Print, Comic Sans MS etc... which then outputs as segeoprint, comicsansms etc. I need it to become Segeo Print, Comic Sans MS once again.

Comment: If I just output  $this->config->get('selectfont') it comes out blank....

Comment: It is difficult to answer exact not see your code. But suppose problem that can be:

1. Check that you serialize object or array when you save this param in configuration. If You not serilize so don't use unserialize.

2. Is you save param as String ? If yes it should be correctly get back from config, If not

Comment: I'am afraid, you can not recover your original data, because these information are lost when you insert. So, you need to check there.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `tbl_url_alias` SET `keyword` = LOWER(`keyword`)

UPDATE `tbl_url_alias` SET `keyword` = REPLACE (`keyword`, ' ', '-')

Run this query in the database, for which table you needed.

Comment: He is fetching the results form the database, if we remove those space and capital form the database, the problem of those not be present there.

Comment: OP do not want to lowercase and remove the capitals. This is his problem, that these things are lost, and want to recover. But. I think, this happens when he inserts the data to the database.

Comment: okies. That is one the reason i convert the upper into lower case, rather than rove it. may it can be done, by replace the capital and spaces with some special character, after that insert the data. And the time of fetching remove those character or replace it with previous one.